# Web service authentication using https giving error

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, ssl

I have written a simple web service and used digest and HTTPS authentication to secure it. I have generated my certificate using keytool present in Java. When I deploy the web-service in Tomcat by creating a .war file, the welcome page of axis is properly being displayed, but when I click on services its giving the following error,

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: https is forbidden
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.preprocessRequest(AxisServlet.java:612)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:241)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

The error is not being displayed when I deploy a website with a servlet. The problem is appearing only when I deploy the axis web services.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at the source for AxisServlet to see if it makes you wiser.

Comment: You should to configure Axis to work over https, as described here: http://buildingaircastles.blogspot.com/2010/12/configuring-axis2-to-expose-web.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use https, then you need to set up axis2.xml as
described in the following document:

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/servlet-transport.html